# Batch Script_ Compare Two String variables

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to compare one variable from user input("yes")
, and predefined("yes") values. However, when I run the .bat file the cmd give me the syntax error message. Please help me how to compare two string values in if statement. thank you.

Here is Code:

```
@echo off
goto main

:main
setlocal

set ans=yes
set /p var=do you have problem?:
echo %var%

if "%var%" == "%ans%"(
    echo there is problem
)
echo.

endlocal
goto :eof
```

Output:
    The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: Put a space before the bracket.

Comment: oh my god... haha you are right. Thank You

Comment: how to compare one string is greater, smaller etc in batch?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@echo off
goto main

:main
setlocal

set ans=yes
set /p var=do you have problem?:

if "%var%" == "%ans%" (echo there is problem) else (echo there is no problem)

endlocal
goto :eof
```

Except I think this is cleaner:

```
@echo off
:main

set /p var=do you have problem?:

if "%var%" == "yes" (echo there is problem) else (echo there is no problem && goto :main)

PAUSE
```